# Is there a cleaner way to refer to variables local to an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In the `CLOCK` object I have the method `initCount()` which sets values to the properties `timeTotal`, `timeZero` and `timeStep`.

I am looking for a way to pass the new values to `timeStep` without declaring local variables. Here's the snippet and below is the greater context of the code:

```
initCount: function() {
    CLOCK.timeTotal = 5;
    let localTimeTotal = 5;
    CLOCK.timeZero = 0;
    let localTimeZero = 0;
    CLOCK.timeStep = localTimeZero / localTimeTotal;
}
```

```js
const CLOCK = {
 initCount: function() {
  CLOCK.timeTotal = 5;
  let localTimeTotal = 5;
  CLOCK.timeZero = 0;
  let localTimeZero = 0;
  CLOCK.timeStep = localTimeZero / localTimeTotal;
 },
 timerReset: function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //INITIALIZING FUNCTIONS AND BUTTONS
  CLOCK.initCount();
 },
 timerSwitch: false,
 sessionSwitch: true,
 timeTotal: undefined,
 timeZero: 0,
 timeStep: undefined,
 timerInterval: undefined,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'this' inside your functions when you're referring to the CLOCK object and execute your functions using the CLOCK namespace, i.e `CLOCK.initCount()`

You might wanna use a class structure for some Object Oriented sugar

#### Your approach - Plain JS OBject

```js
const CLOCK = {
 initCount: function() {
  this.timeTotal = 5;
  this.timeZero = 0;
  this.timeStep = this.timeZero / this.timeTotal;
 },
 timerReset: function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //INITIALIZING FUNCTIONS AND BUTTONS
  this.initCount();
 },
 timerSwitch: false,
 sessionSwitch: true,
 timeTotal: undefined,
 timeZero: 0,
 timeStep: undefined,
 timerInterval: undefined,
}

CLOCK.initCount();
console.log(CLOCK);
```